# Ways to optimize DB2 Query

Tags: view, db2, db2-400

I have used the below SQL statement to create a DB2 view. Can someone help me on how to improve this view performance as it runs slow sometimes.

The one thing I noted is that it runs slow the first time but then for subsequent runs, it picks up speed. I have analyzed with the visual explain but when it runs slow, I don't see any index advises. So not really sure how to optimize this.

```
--  Generate SQL 
--  Version:                    V7R4M0 190621 
--  Generated on:               02/09/21 03:08:31 
--  Relational Database:        BIGBLUE 
--  Standards Option:           Db2 for i 
CREATE VIEW IESQAFILE.PSCMPORDVW  
    AS 
    WITH INPROGRESS AS 
     ( 
     SELECT 
     DIODR# 
     , DIDISP 
     , DIUNIT 
     , DISTST 
     , DIAPRV 
     , DIETAD 
     , DITRLR AS TRAILER_ID 
     , DIDR1 
     , DIETAT 
     FROM 
     IESQAFILE.LOAD 
     WHERE 
     DIETAD <> 0 
     AND DIETAT <> '0000' 
     ORDER BY 
     1 
     ) 
    , STOPGROUP AS 
     ( 
     SELECT 
     SOORD STOPORDER 
     , COUNT(*) STOPSREMAIN 
     , MIN(SOSTP#) NEXTSTOP 
     , MAX(SOAPPR) APPTREQ 
     FROM 
     PAVT.STOP 
     INNER JOIN 
     INPROGRESS 
     ON 
     DIODR# = SOORD 
     WHERE 
     SOARDT = 0 
     GROUP BY 
     SOORD 
     ORDER BY 
     1 
     ) 
    , STOPAPPTS AS 
     ( 
     SELECT 
     SOORD APPTORDER 
     , SOCUST STOPCUST 
     , SOEDA ETADATE 
     , SOETA ETATIME 
     , SOADT1 EARLYDATE 
     , SOATM1 EARLYTIME 
     , SOADT2 LATEDATE 
     , SOATM2 LATETIME 
     , SOCTYC NEXTCITY 
     , SOSTP# APPTSTOP 
     , SOST NEXTSTATE 
     FROM 
     IESQAFILE.STOPOFF 
     INNER JOIN 
     STOPGROUP 
     ON 
     STOPORDER = SOORD 
     AND NEXTSTOP = SOSTP# 
     ) 
    SELECT 
     ORDER_NUMBER 
    , SHIPPER_ID 
    , SHIPPER_NAME 
    , SHIPPER_ADDRESS_1 
    , SHIPPER_ADDRESS_2 
    , SHIPPER_CITY 
    , SHIPPER_ST 
    , SHIPPER_ZIP 
    , SHIPPER_ZIP_EXT 
    , LOAD_AT_ID 
    , LOAD_AT_NAME 
    , LOAD_AT_ADDRESS_1 
    , LOAD_AT_ADDRESS_2 
    , LOAD_AT_CITY 
    , LOAD_AT_ST 
    , LOAD_AT_ZIP 
    , LOAD_AT_ZIP_EXT 
    , LOAD_AT_LATITUDE 
    , LOAD_AT_LONGITUDE 
    , EARLY_PU_DATE_TIME 
    , LATE_PU_DATE_TIME 
    , EARLY_DELV_DATE_TIME 
    , EST_REVENUE 
    , ORDER_DIV 
    , CONSIGNEE_ID 
    , CONSIGNEE_NAME 
    , CONSIGNEE_ADDRESS_1 
    , CONSIGNEE_ADDRESS_2 
    , CONSIGNEE_CITY 
    , CONSIGNEE_ST 
    , CONSIGNEE_ZIP 
    , CONSIGNEE_ZIP_EXT 
    , CONSIGNEE_LATITUDE 
    , CONSIGNEE_LONGITUDE 
    , TRAILER_TYPE 
    , ORDER_MESSAGE 
    , ADDITIONAL_STOPS 
    , CMDTY_CODE 
    , CMDTY_DESCRIPTION 
    , ORDER_MILES 
    , ORDER_WGT 
    , ORIGIN_CITY_CODE 
    , ORIGIN_CITY 
    , ORIGIN_ST 
    , DEST_CITY_CODE 
    , DEST_CITY_NAME 
    , DEST_ST 
    , PICK_UP_AREA 
    , PLAN_INFO 
    , NUMBER_LDS 
    , NUMBER_DISP 
    , SHIP_DATE_TIME 
    , NEW_PICKUP_AREA 
    , EQUIPMENT_NUMBER 
    , APPT_REQ 
    , APPT_MADE 
    , PRE_T_SEQ 
    , PRE_T_AREA 
    , LOAD_DISPATCHED 
    , CUST_SERV_REP 
    , NEGOTIATIONS 
    , 
     ( 
     CASE 
     WHEN UNUNIT IS NOT NULL 
     THEN UNUNIT 
     ELSE ' ' 
     END 
     ) 
     UNIT_DISPATCHED 
    , 
     ( 
     CASE 
     WHEN UNSUPR IS NOT NULL 
     THEN UNSUPR 
     ELSE ' ' 
     END 
     ) 
     DRIVER_MGR_CODE 
    , COALESCE(SUPNAM, ' ') DRIVER_MGR_NAME 
    , 
     ( 
     CASE 
     WHEN UNFMGR IS NOT NULL 
     THEN UNFMGR 
     ELSE ' ' 
     END 
     ) 
     FLEET_MGR_CODE 
    , COALESCE(FLTNAM,' ') FLEET_MGR_NAME 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            , 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ( 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 CASE 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             WHEN UNTRL1 IS NOT NULL 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             THEN UNTRL1 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ELSE ' ' 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         END 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ) 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 TRAILER_ID, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         DIDISP DISPATCH_NUMBER, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             (COALESCE(BCMCNEW, ' ')) FED_MC_ID, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 DIUNIT DISPATCHED_UNIT, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             CASE 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             WHEN UNETAD <> 0 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 AND UNETAT = '' 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     THEN SMIS.CVTDATETIM(CHAR(UNETAD),'0000', ( 
     SELECT 
     SUBSTR(DATA_AREA_VALUE, 1109, 2) AS TIMEZONE 
     FROM 
     TABLE(QSYS2.DATA_AREA_INFO('COMPAN', '*LIBL')) 
     ) 
     ) 
     WHEN UNETAD <> 0 
     THEN SMIS.CVTDATETIM(CHAR(UNETAD),UNETAT, ( 
     SELECT 
     SUBSTR(DATA_AREA_VALUE, 1109, 2) AS TIMEZONE 
     FROM 
     TABLE(QSYS2.DATA_AREA_INFO('COMPAN', '*LIBL')) 
     ) 
     ) 
     WHEN UNETAD = 0 
     THEN '0000-00-00T00:00:00-00:00' 
     END AS ETA_DATE_TIME, 
     NEXTSTOP , CASE 
     WHEN SOARDT <> 0 
     AND SOARTM = '' 
     THEN SMIS.CVTDATETIM(CHAR(SOARDT),'0000', ( 
     SELECT 
     SUBSTR(DATA_AREA_VALUE, 1109, 2) AS TIMEZONE 
     FROM 
     TABLE(QSYS2.DATA_AREA_INFO('COMPAN', '*LIBL')) 
     ) 
     ) 
     WHEN SOARDT <> 0 
     THEN SMIS.CVTDATETIM(CHAR(SOARDT),SOARTM, ( 
     SELECT 
     SUBSTR(DATA_AREA_VALUE, 1109, 2) AS TIMEZONE 
     FROM 
     TABLE(QSYS2.DATA_AREA_INFO('COMPAN', '*LIBL')) 
     ) 
     ) 
     WHEN SOARDT = 0 
     THEN '0000-00-00T00:00:00-00:00' 
     END AS STOP_ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME 
    , CASE 
     WHEN SOLUDT <> 0 
     AND SOLUTM = '' 
     THEN SMIS.CVTDATETIM(CHAR(SOLUDT),'0000', ( 
     SELECT 
     SUBSTR(DATA_AREA_VALUE, 1109, 2) AS TIMEZONE 
     FROM 
     TABLE(QSYS2.DATA_AREA_INFO('COMPAN', '*LIBL')) 
     ) 
     ) 
     WHEN SOLUDT <> 0 
     THEN SMIS.CVTDATETIM(CHAR(SOLUDT),SOLUTM, ( 
     SELECT 
     SUBSTR(DATA_AREA_VALUE, 1109, 2) AS TIMEZONE 
     FROM 
     TABLE(QSYS2.DATA_AREA_INFO('COMPAN', '*LIBL')) 
     ) 
     ) 
     WHEN SOLUDT = 0 
     THEN '0000-00-00T00:00:00-00:00' 
     END AS STOP_DEPART_DATE_TIME 
    , ORBAMT ORDER_INV_AMT 
    , ORARST AR_STATUS_FLAG 
    , DISTST SETTLEMENT_FLAG 
    , DIAPRV APPROVED_FOR_PAY 
    , BCCARR CARRIER_CODE 
    , BCNAME CARRIER_NAME 
    , BCADDR CARRIER_ADDRESS_1 
    , BCADR2 CARRIER_ADDRESS_2 
    , BCCITY CARRIER_CITY 
    , BCST CARRIER_ST 
    , BCZIP CARRIER_ZIP 
    FROM 
     INPROGRESS 
     INNER JOIN 
     IESQAFILE.PSMAINORVW A 
     ON 
     DIODR# = ORDER_NUMBER 
     AND DIDISP = NUMBER_DISP 
     AND 
     ( 
     SUBSTR(ORDER_NUMBER, 1, 2) <> 'DH' 
     AND SUBSTR(ORDER_NUMBER, 1, 1) <> 'M' 
     ) 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     IESQAFILE.STOPOFF 
     ON 
     DIODR# = SOORD 
     AND SOSTP# = 90 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     IESQAFILE.LMCARR 
     ON 
     DIUNIT = BCCARR 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     IESQAFILE.MMILES 
     ON 
     MMORD# = DIODR# 
     AND MMRECTYPE = 'D' 
     AND MMDSP# = DIDISP 
     EXCEPTION JOIN 
     IESQAFILE.ORDBILL B 
     ON 
     B.ORODR# = DIODR# 
     AND B.ORSEQ = ' ' 
     AND ORARST = '1' 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     STOPGROUP 
     ON 
     STOPORDER = DIODR# 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     STOPAPPTS 
     ON 
     APPTORDER = STOPORDER 
     AND APPTSTOP = NEXTSTOP 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     IESQAFILE.UNITS 
     ON 
     UNUNIT = DIUNIT 
     AND UNORD# = ORDER_NUMBER 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     IESQAFILE.SUPMAST 
     ON 
     SUPCDE = UNSUPR 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     IESQAFILE.FLTMAST 
     ON 
     UNFMGR = FLTCDE 
    WHERE 
     DIETAD <> 0 
     AND DIETAT <> '0000'   
    RCDFMT PSCMPORDVW ;
```

Comment: By default, Db2 for i does a few thing behind the scenes to improve performance when the same statement is executed repeatedly.  So I'm not surprised that you see a difference between the first run an subsequent ones.  How big a difference are we talking about?

Comment: You should include an example of the SELECT you'd use to access the view.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the Visual Explain (VE) data (and it's not really something easily sharable here) giving you a "magic wand" answer not likely.

I'm surprised you don't see any indexes advised.  But even so, you should be able to compare the VE data between "fast" and "slow" runs to see where the differences are. Make sure you have "View"-->"Highlighting"-->"Expensive Icons"-->... turned on.  Also check "Options"-->"Attribute Detail" and "Options"-->"Graph Detail"...

Always a good idea to be using the latest and greatest version (1.1.8.6) of Access Client Solutions (ACS) which includes the Run SQL Script & VE components.

A couple of things jump out, an Encoded Vector Index (EVI) that include aggregates(count,min,max) might help here...

```
select soord stoporder
                ,count(*) stopsremain
                ,min(sostp#) nextstop
                ,max(soappr) apptreq
           from pavt.stop
```

And index (or two) with derived columns `substr(order_number,....)` might help here:

```
from inprogress
         inner join iesqafile.psmainorvw a
           on diodr# = order_number
             and didisp = number_disp
             and (substr(order_number, 1, 2) <> 'DH'
               and substr(order_number, 1, 1) <> 'M')
```

Again VE is your friend, you'll have to dig into what's going on and where the time is being spent.

Break the various parts of your statement down and try to optimize individual components when possible.  Hopefully, the gains will remain when you put it back together.

One thing to remember, a view is performance neutral.  It neither helps nor hurts performance.

You don't give an example of how you access the view, but have you considered making use of user defined table functions (UDTF)?  While the query engine attempts to push down selection criteria, a UDTF's parameters make it easy for you to explicitly include selection criteria.  You might even benefit from encapsulating the statement in a UDTF and building the view over the UDTF.  You can see an example (via Generate SQL Source) for the `message_queue_info` view & UDTF in QSYS2 that IBM provided.